# Set window title in iTerm with zsh

Tags: macos, zsh, iterm2

I am using iTerm2 in my mac with zsh. I have set `DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE="true"` within .zshrc. Now I can use `title` to set window and tab titles. But it the title which appears in the title has the running process name appended to it, e.g. `(zsh)` while idle. How can I remove this?